# Can I add custom Icons to the Heroicons Library?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, heroicons

I love how easy they are to work with so i want to "import" my own Icons to use like HeroIcons.
i dont want to create a Component that returns an SVG with the styles, scince this does not seem to give a result as easy to work with as Heroicons do.

I searched the Internet but did not find anything about it, but it seems to me like this should be a fairly common issue